# python: groupby (merge) next lines with previous line if they start with same match pattern in text data

Tags: python, dataframe, text, nltk

I have a file.txt with data group (AAA-(n)) that is very large. Many lines in the file have the same tag (ex. AB) between line AAA -(n)  to  AAA-(n+1) in the file. I want to put them into one line. For example:

```
AAA-1
XX-a
AB-a
AB-b
AB-c
numb-a
lime-a
lime-b
XX-b
AB-d
AB-e
lime-c
AAA-2
.
.
AAA-n
.
.
```

My desired output is:

```
AAA-1
XX-a
AB-a;b;c
numb-a
lime-a;b
XX-b
AB-d;e
lime-c
AAA-2
.
.
.
AAA-n
.
.
```

I tried this:

```
from itertools import groupby, count

counter = count()
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for key, group in groupby(f, lambda s: next(counter) if s.startswith('AAA') or s.startswith('XX') else -1):
        print(';'.join(s.rstrip('\n') for s in group))
```

Out:

```
AAA-1
XX-a
AB-a;AB-b;AB-c;numb-a;lime-a;lime-b
XX-b
AB-d;AB-e;lime-c
AAA-2
```

plz, help me to avoid grouping other tags with **AB** and remove tags after group?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**: Updated to get correct output

Here is what I came up with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'data': dat})
df['data'] = df['data'].str.split('-')
df['tag'] = [x[0] for x in df['data']]
df['tail'] = [x[1] for x in df['data']]

i = 0
while i < (len(df) - 1): 
    tails = [df.iat[i, 2]]
    j = 1
    while(df.iat[i, 1] == df.iat[i+j, 1]):
        tails.append(df.iat[i+j, 2])
        j += 1
    df.loc[i, 'tails'] = tails
    i += j

df.dropna(how='any', axis=0, inplace=True)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df.drop(columns=['data', 'tail'], inplace=True)
df['final'] = [df.at[i, 'tag'] + '-' + ';'.join(df.at[i, 'tails']) for i in range(len(df))]
```

Output:

### [image]

First approach that comes to mind would be to split the trailing character from the tag and place in a separate column. Assuming you're using Pandas and it's in a DF already:

```
df['data'] = df['data'].str.split('-')
df['tag'] = [x[0] for x in df['data']]
df['tail'] = [x[1] for x in df['data']]
```

So now you have a column with the original data, a column with the tag, and a column with the tail.

[image]

Now you can group by the tag:

```
grouped = df.groupby('tag')
```

From here youcan achieve what you want using a lambda function:

```
out = grouped.agg({'tail': lambda t: ''.join(t)})
```

[image]

From here you can reset the index, join into a single string with a dash, whatever you want.

Comment: I don't want want to group all similar tags together, want to group them at the same place when AB comes after XX. All tags will repeat after AAA in the data file and don't want to group XX and AAA. plz, see my desire output.

Comment: @ LiamFiddler, Your approach is correct [solved] but when working with a large data (40K + rows) it is taking more than 30 minutes and I have data with 200K rows. This is why I decided to work with the text file.

Comment: To be honest if there is a faster way to do this I am not sure what it is. Because of how you want your output formatted, the nested `while` loops become necessary, which is likely where the hangup is. Groupby would be significantly faster, but as mentioned before that doesn't give the desired output.